# Manipulation of array of objects in javascript using lodash or underscore.js

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of object in this format:

```
data= [ { 'a': [{"_id":"aa","type":"credit","amount":500}]},
        { 'b': [{"_id":"ba","type":"credit","amount":600},
                {"_id":"bb","type":"refund","amount":200}]},
        { 'a': [{"_id":"aaa","type":"credit","amount":600},
                {"_id":"aab","type":"credit","amount":200}]}]
```

All i want to do is to achieve an object like this:

```
result=[ { 'a': 500 },{ 'b': 600},{ 'a': 800} ]
```

This basically adds up the amount field from the objects which does not have a type refund.

I have tried something with _.reject and _.sumBy of lodash but failed to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```js
const data = [{'a':[{"_id":"aa","type":"credit","amount":500}]},{'b':[{"_id":"ba","type":"credit","amount":600},{"_id":"bb","type":"refund","amount":200}]}]

const sum = (items) => _.chain(items)
  .reject({ type: 'refund' })
  .sumBy('amount')
  .value();

const res = _.map(data, item => _.mapValues(item, sum));

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Beautiful, clean answer

Comment: [It is not okay to add another question after your original question was solved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296489/when-is-it-ok-to-extend-a-question-with-another-question-after-initial-answers), if this answer solved your question, please mark it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Are you opposed to using standard javascript?

In this example, I use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate through each part of the array and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum the amounts.

```js
const objs = [{'a':[{"_id":"aa","type":"credit","amount":500}]},{'b':[{"_id":"ba","type":"credit","amount":600},{"_id":"bb","type":"refund","amount":200}]}]

let newObjs = objs.map((o) => {
  let key = Object.keys(o)[0];
  let amount = o[key].length > 1 ? o[key].reduce((a, b) => {
      return {
        amount: a.amount + (b.type == "refund" ? 0 : b.amount)
      }
    }).amount :
    o[key][0].type == "refund" ? 0 : o[key][0].amount;
  return JSON.parse(`{"${key}":${amount}}`)
})

console.log(newObjs)
```

---

> The **map()** method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

---

> The **reduce()** method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.

---